# Scaling issue in BigDecimal(java) for exponential notation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In our application, we need to check whether the given number is in range or not 
and for this we are using below code -

```
 boolean isValidRangeNumber(Double no,int precision, int scale){
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(no.toString());
            int intPartLength = precision - scale;
            int size = (bigDecimal.longValue() + "").toString().length();

            if(bigDecimal.precision() <= precision && bigDecimal.scale() <= scale && size <= intPartLength)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
```

But when we are calling `isValidRangeNumber(0.0000009, 10,7)` than its failing as `bigDecimal.scale()` is giving 8 which can be max 7 whereas its a valid number. Please suggest, what is wrong with this BigDecimal usage.

Comment: Can explain what the validation is supposed to do? It is hard to infer correct behaviour from buggy code.

Comment: it checks whether the entered number have required digits before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect following :

```
bigDecimal.toPlainString() // This will show 0.00000090 -> scale of 8, appends trailing 0
```

Because of an extra trailing zero, following condition evaluates to false.

```
bigDecimal.scale() <= scale // 8 <= 7
```

You can change into following :

```
boolean isValidRangeNumber(Double no, int precision, int scale) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(no.toString()).stripTrailingZeros(); //Get rid of trailing zeros
    bigDecimal.toPlainString();
    int intPartLength = precision - scale;

    int size = (bigDecimal.longValue() + "").toString().length();

    if (bigDecimal.precision() <= precision && bigDecimal.scale() <= scale
            && size <= intPartLength)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, by doing so its giving correct scale but it would be good if you can give a brief about this behaviour of BigDecimal and on why bigDecimal.precision() is giving 2 which should be 1 (count of significant digits)

Comment: That I doubt you have to look further into documentation of BigDecimal.